# trying to use window.opener technique to call parent js function from child popup window?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the js window.opener technique to return a selected value from a child window back to a parent js function.  Here's a url to a zip file where I set up a basic poc:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gle9sou3gj770ej/WindowOpenerPOC.zip

LaunchPage.html is used to open ResolveCaseDialog.html.  The Submit button on ResolveCaseDialog submits the selected "Resolution Type" value to window.opener.ProcessReturnValue().

However, when I click the Submit button, the ResolveCaseDialog js throws the following exception: "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Can you please take a look at this setup and let me know if there's a trick to making this work that I'm missing?

Comment: sounds like cross-site scripting to me

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a similar problem too, you have to use

```
opener.ProcessReturnValue();
```

instead of

```
window.opener.ProcessReturnValue()
```

This works for Internet Explorer but doesen't work on Chrome.

Now the problem is that is not specified the port.
We are a step forward but the problem isn't resolved yet.

Here there is an example:
[call opener function](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfmyd7xk5eee94i/example.zip)

The main page is testA, that calls testB.